# Difference between Google Analytics API v4 (no result) and dashboard

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to retrieve separately **ga:userAgeBracket** and **ga:userGender** using Google Analytics Report API v4 using a filter on eventCategory and eventAction.

From GA Dashboard, i'm able to retrieve the data even if there is only ~ 2.4k users and ~5.6k sessions. The repartition is 178 Males and 142 Females.

I'm trying to get the same result with the API but it's return nothing. I'm testing with https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer with the same filters ect.

Is there any limit on the API **ONLY** when there is a small amount of data ? or another reason ?

EDIT: With another account with more data, and i still have the issue. Here are some screenshots

[image: GA Filters]

[image: GA Gender from filters]

[image: Query Explorer]

Comment: can you paste the query you're trying to run, or screenshots of the settings of metrics/dimensions selected/

Comment: I added screeshoots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created a segment in GA webUI and is comparing the results to "filters" in the explorer. You should be applying the same segment instead for consistency. Once you save the segment in webUI, it should be available in the "segment" field as a selection.

Your filtering also uses the "=~" regex match operator instead of the "=@" contains operator. Try this and you should have results.